# css take afect only after turning off and then turning on property in firebug

Tags: css, firebug

Does anybody possible reason why *(after submit)* css property (in my case `margin: 0 auto;`)
stop to work?

But after I disable it on firebug and then enable it back, it *(by miracle)* work again.

See Pictures:

![1]: http://postimg.org/image/r9i6c8ayh/ "Not working but in firebug is corecctly set"

![2]: http://postimg.org/image/buxdrj1f7/ "1.Turn it off in firebug 2.Turn it on and it work correctly, but only after this trick."

Comment: Which properties does the <body> has ? cause i can see your #center inherit some properties of the body ? Maybe there's a clue there

Comment: Sorry my fault, margin is not missing, whole screen is moved to the right, I did not noticed that down on browser scroll bar, silly me :) But still why post move my screen to the right. What should I look for, probably some jquery, to prevent this screen moving after submit.